# Convert DXBC to DXIL (DirectX Bytecode to DirectX Intermediate Language)

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl, directx-12, direct3d12

Microsoft's open source [DirectX Shader Compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) describes the format of a new intermediate language (IL) for HLSL shaders called DXIL.

The documentation makes reference to a converter from the previous HLSL IL, called DXBC, to the new DXIL: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/master/docs/DXIL.rst.

However, I am unable to find the referenced dxbc2dxil tool, or any other way to convert DXBC to DXIL.  I have tried passing DXBC files to the various tools in the DirectX Shader Compiler project, but none have accepted plain DXBC as input.

Is there currently a way to obtain DXIL from old DXBC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of this documentation is that Microsoft will take charge of only providing DXIR to the vendor's drivers in the future. The DXBC2DXIL is a Microsoft internal only module.

To my knowledge, nothing in the DirectX Shader Compiler repository has the capability to translate a DXBC IL to a DXIL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @galop1n.  Having that tool publicly available would be nice, so hopefully Microsoft will release some version of it eventually.

Comment: Confirmed that dxbc2dxil is not currently public: https://twitter.com/mlrdev/status/895140130553384962

Comment: has been open sourced at https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/tree/master/projects/dxilconv/lib/DxbcConverter

Answer (score 0):

See this project for a working hack: https://github.com/Nukem9/Dxbc2Dxil

They use "dxilconv.dll" from win10 to create an instance of the undocumented DXBC->DXIL converter.